# Days of last month inPL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, date-arithmetic

How can I get all the Days of the previous month in PL/SQL ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)) + level
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY
        level <= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)) - LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
begin
for i in 1..to_char(trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1,'dd') loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Or if you want date :

```
begin
for i in 1..to_char(trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1,'dd') loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i+trunc(trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1,'mm')-1);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
WITH d AS
(
SELECT TRUNC ( sysdate, 'MM' ) - 1 AS dt
FROM dual
)
SELECT dt + LEVEL
FROM d
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS (dt, 1) - dt
```